# When will the Ubuntu 16.10 for ARM be released?

Tags: 16.10, arm

I found the Ubuntu Server 16.10 has been released, and how about the Ubuntu 16.10 for ARM?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.10 has been released. Packages that build for *armhf* and *arm64* are also in the archive. There are however, no generic images that can be installed on any ARM device. In order to install on an ARM device, custom images specific to a device must be built, in order to boot properly.

There is an [arm64 server ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/16.10/release/ubuntu-16.10-server-arm64.iso) and [Raspberry Pi 2 image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/16.10/release/ubuntu-16.10-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz) available, however.